# Allow ECS task to AssumeRole into another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726145/how-do-i-have-an-ecs-task-assume-a-role-from-another-aws-account) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694971/cant-grant-cross-account-access-to-a-ecs-tasks-role) but I'm not able to deploy a role into a child account which allows an ECS task running in the parent account to AssumeRole into it.

Terraform code:

```hcl
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cross-account-assume-role-child" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        "arn:aws:sts::${var.master_account_ID}:assumed-role/${var.cross_account_role_name}"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run terraform the plan succeeds but the apply fails with such an error:

```
Error: failed creating IAM Role (ECS-cross-account-child-role): 
MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: 
"AWS":"arn:aws:sts::<AWS Account ID>:assumed-role/ECS-cross-account-master-role"
```

I get the same error if I try to manually update the policy like above in the AWS console so this isn't due to terraform.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arn you need to specify in the policy is the one of the IAM role, not of the assumed credentials:

```
arn:aws:iam::${var.master_account_ID}:role/${var.cross_account_role_name}
```

Instead of of `sts` and `assumed-role`